# What are the all group automorphism of $Z_{60}$ sending 5 to 25?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I am looking for all group automorphism of $Z_{60}$ sending 5 to 25.

I can see that all 16 generators are mapped to same elements and identity element is mapped to identity as well. Also that 30 is mapped to itself as it has order of 2. 
But there are still many elements unmapped.

Is there any other conditions that automorphism must satisfy?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I fixed it.

Comment: What is $Z_{60}$? Do you mean $\Bbb Z / 60 \Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\Bbb Z_{60}\cong \Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_{12}$, with $5\mapsto(0,5)$ and $25\mapsto (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chinese remainder theorem $\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ for example or bruteforce your way through the task by sending a chosen generator of $\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z}$ to another generator of $\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z}$. That means you should understand the generators. To get a grasp on all generators you have to consider all positive integers less than $60$ that are coprime to $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Comment: If you do not feel comfortable with that, thats fine. You can also do it the other way that I mentioned why does not use products of groups.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. As I have not studied a group of product of two group, I’m unsure how to use th isomorphism you gave me.             But I noticed that checking what are mapped to 1 is enough to identify an automorphism. By modular arithmetics, I got f(1) =5,17 ,29 ,41 or 53. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry I had trouble sending comments

Comment: I have not checked, but what you need to to in that case is find all generators $x$ such that $5x = 25 \; \text{mod} \; 60$. Sounds like that was what you did.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad that I could help.